Prisma One to Many relation not visible in database and connect option not working
this is Prisma Schema
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

// Models

model User {
  id   Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  type UserRole @default(PATIENT)

  patientRelations  Patient?
  nurseRelations    Nurse?
  headDeptRelations headDept?

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  nationalID   BigInt  @unique(map: "nationalID") @db.BigInt
  email        String? @unique(map: "UserMail")
  phone        BigInt? @unique(map: "UserPhone") @db.BigInt
  name         String?
  passwordHash String?
}

enum UserRole {
  PATIENT
  NURSE
  HEADDEPT
}

//Users models (unchanged)
model Nurse {
  patients   Patient[] // OneToMany Relationship (Nurse has many Paitents)
  department Department @relation("NurseToDept", fields: [depID], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  depID      Int
  isActive   Boolean?   @default(true)
  user       User       @relation(fields: [nurseID], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  nurseID    Int        @unique

  @@id([nurseID])
  @@index([depID])
}

model Patient {
  nurse     Nurse @relation(fields: [nurseID], references: [nurseID], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  nurseID   Int
  user      User  @relation(fields: [patientID], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  patientID Int   @unique

  @@id([patientID])
  @@index([nurseID])
}

model headDept {
  user       User        @relation(fields: [headDepID], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  headDepID  Int         @unique
  department Department?
  depID      Int         @unique

  @@id([headDepID])
  @@index([depID])
}

model Department {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String    @unique(map: "DepartmentName")
  nurses     Nurse[]   @relation("NurseToDept") // OneToMany Relationship (Department has many Nurses)
  headDept   headDept? @relation(fields: [headDeptID], references: [headDepID], onDelete: SetNull)
  headDeptID Int?      @unique
}

and this is a simple function that create Head-Department data
const assignHeadToDep = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const ids = req.params.ids.split("-");
    const headDeptID:number = +ids[0];
    const depID:number = +ids[1];
    // headDeptID - depID
    const headDept = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: +headDeptID },
    });
    const dep = await prisma.department.findUnique({ where: { id: depID } });

    if (!dep) {
      res
        .status(404)
        .json({ message: `Department with ID:${depID} Doesn't Exists` });
      return;
    }
    if (!headDept) {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: `HeadDept with ID:${headDeptID} Doesn't Exists`,
      });
      return;
    }

    await prisma.headDept
      .create({
        data: {  <-- error generated here 
          depID: depID,
          headDepID: headDeptID,
          department: { connect: { id: depID } }, <-- error when adding this line
          user: { connect: { id: headDeptID } }, <-- error when adding this line
        },
      })
      .then((result) => {
        res
          .status(200)
          .json({ message: "HeadDept assigned successfully", result });
      });
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    const err: Error = error as Error;
    handleError(err, res);
  }
};

The error typescript shows
Type '{ depID: number; headDepID: number; department: { connect: { id: number; }; }; user: { connect: { id: number; }; }; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<headDeptCreateInput, headDeptUncheckedCreateInput> & headDeptUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & headDeptCreateInput)'.
  Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
    Type '{ connect: { id: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(4993, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: headDeptSelect<DefaultArgs> | null | undefined; include?: headDeptInclude<DefaultArgs> | null | undefined; data: (Without<...> & headDeptUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & headDeptCreateInput); }'
(property) data: (Prisma.Without<Prisma.headDeptCreateInput, Prisma.headDeptUncheckedCreateInput> & Prisma.headDeptUncheckedCreateInput) | (Prisma.Without<Prisma.headDeptUncheckedCreateInput, Prisma.headDeptCreateInput> & Prisma.headDeptCreateInput)
The data needed to create a headDept.

I'm trying to create a User that can be either a [ Patient - Nurse - HeadDept ], so a made model user that contain the shared data between them and made an enum to discriminate which user.
the other user models get their id from the main user model as One-to-one relation so that wouldn't be many or duplicated id refer to the same user
creating a user isn't the problem but creating the Patient - Nurse or HeadDept is the problem, whenever trying to make a connection it always failed and showing errors plus I can't see the One-To-Many relation columns in my database like in the nurse model there're many patients and in department there're many nurses. these columns do not exist.
using the connect option in Prisma isn't working.
what seem to be the problem, and what should I do?

Either the link to your repo is incorrect or your repo is private. If you can make the repo accessible, people can clone your repo and try to troubleshoot.

thanks for reminding me, I change the visibility to public so that everyone can see it.
I didn't push that last change that include this problem to my repo but if anyone would like to see the project to get better understanding to my problem, please take a look.

Why not push the code with the problem into the repo? Make a separate branch, name it referring to Stack Overflow, and push the code.

hi @PerttuHaliseva I just created a branch as you requested.

The solution
The solution is to remove all the extra fields from create statements.
Read the generated types and understand what you connect and how.
Explanation
Alright, I pulled your branch and seeing the generated types in my IDE helped clarify the problem.
You have some issues with your Prisma schema. To me, it seems like you are mixing relational database modeling and conventions with how object-relational mapping is used. You really should go through the Prisma documentation and tutorials and try to rethink how to handle e.g. "the Prisma way".
That being said, let's focus on the problem you are asking about. This is your starting point:
await prisma.headDept
  .create({
    data: {  <-- error generated here 
      depID: depID,
      headDepID: headDeptID,
      department: { connect: { id: depID } }, <-- error when adding this line
      user: { connect: { id: headDeptID } }, <-- error when adding this line
    },
  });

model headDept {
  user      User @relation(fields: [headDepID], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  headDepID Int  @unique

  department Department?
  depID      Int         @unique

  @@id([headDepID])
  @@index([depID])
}

headDept.user and department are relational fields which refer to User and Department models, respectively. headDepID and depID are scalar fields; the former is a foreign key pointing to User.id, the latter's purpose I don't really understand - is it there just for indexing?
Take a look at what are the generated Prisma Client types for headDept.create():
data: XOR<headDeptCreateInput, headDeptUncheckedCreateInput>

export type headDeptCreateInput = {
  depID: number
  user: UserCreateNestedOneWithoutHeadDeptRelationsInput // basically create, connect or connectOrCreate
  department?: DepartmentCreateNestedOneWithoutHeadDeptInput // create, connect or connectOrCreate
}

export type headDeptUncheckedCreateInput = {
  headDepID: number
  depID: number
  department?: DepartmentUncheckedCreateNestedOneWithoutHeadDeptInput // create, connect or connectOrCreate
}

This tells us that shape of data should be either of the above types. You are trying to add extra fields to your create statement and this results in an error. Keeping this in mind, your statement should be:
// EITHER:
await prisma.headDept
  .create({
    data: {
      user: { connect: { id: headDeptID } },
      depID: depID,
    },
  });

// OR:
await prisma.headDept
  .create({
    data: {
      headDepID: headDeptID,
      depID: depID,    
    },
  });



Going further
Again: read the Prisma client types. E.g. in VS Code, right click on your create() statement and select "Go to type definition".

I want to further emphasize that there are problems with your Prisma schema, and you should learn to model your data and use the library the way it is intended. I am not saying this to be mean, but learning the basics will help you avoid these kinds of problems.
For example:
model User {
  id   Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  type UserRole @default(PATIENT)

  // Rename fields to avoid redundant "relations"
  // Rename headDept model to avoid unnecessary abbrevations, use correct capitalization
  patient        Patient?
  nurse          Nurse?
  headDepartment HeadDepartment?
  // ...
}

See the docs for naming conventions.

the idea of me creating the Prisma schema in that way so that I don't have to duplicate lines. if you look to the previous Prisma schema they're only a Patient and Nurse with normal relation One-To-Many between them but they have the same columns of (name, email, nationalID, phone...etc., So i made a user model that have the data of every user whatsoever and other models for specific data to that user. then face the problem of duplicate id in every model so i made a relation between every model with user model to get an id. and end up with the connect problem as you can see

@El-BaraaRadwan I don't follow your reasoning behind the relations, but that is outside the scope of my answer in any case. I spent 2.5 hours setting up a local DB, looking into your problem, linking documentation and offering advice. If your problem was resolved by my answer, please upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer. If not, then please clarify why my answer does not work for you. Your writing another answer feels disrespectful towards my efforts to help you.

I'm sorry for you feeling that way, it's my first-time using stack overflow, so i didn't knew how to respond to your answer other that writing an answer myself to clarify the problem
I would love if you highlighted how to handle Prisma models more efficiency
